# Selecting items in a listbox using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selection

I am using two ListBox controls in my WPF window that are identical (identical = `ItemSource` of both the ListBox is same and so they look same) and the selection mode on both the ListBoxes is set to Multiple.

Lets call the ListBoxes `LB1` and `LB2` for the time being, now when I click an item in `LB1`, I want the same item in `LB2` to get selected automatically i.e if I select 3 items in LB1 using either <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the same items in `LB2` get selected.

Have dug the Listbox properties like `SelectedItems`, `SelectedIndex` etc but no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place a SelectionChanged event on your first listbox

```
LB1.SelectionChanged += LB1_SelectionChanged;
```

Then implement the SelectionChanged method like so:

```
void LB1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LB2.SelectedItems.Clear();
    foreach(var selected in LB1.SelectedItems)
    {
        LB2.SelectedItems.Add(selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi There,
Thank you very much your help is appreciated, the code snippet you gave works like a charm.

Best Regards
@nand

Answer (score 0):

Did you try SetSelected?

```
listBox2.SetSelected(1, True)
```

You can use it like this

```
private void DoLB2Selection()
{
   // Loop through all items the ListBox.
   for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
   {
      // Determine if the item is selected.
      if(listBox1.GetSelected(x) == true)
         // Deselect all items that are selected.
         listBox2.SetSelected(x,true);
   }
```

use the selected items from LB1 as a index in LB2

Comment: Hi PoweRoy,
Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately WPF does not expose the SetSelected property for Listboxes. I tried googling for it (setselected) but couldn't get a solution and hence this post

Best Regards
@nand